# How to sign a string using SHA1WITHRSA, X509Certificate2 and BouncyCastle in .NET?

Tags: vb.net, rsa, bouncycastle, sha1, x509certificate2

I am currently working on a project where I have to sign an XML document to send it to a webservice.

I have tried several code snippets I could find here and around the web, but have not yet achieved my goal.

This is the function I currently use, but it throws an exception because *modulus* is negative.

```vbnet
Function Encrypt_XML(sUnsigned_Snippet As String, oCertificate As X509Certificate2) As String
    Dim Parameters As RSAParameters = CType(oCertificate.PrivateKey, RSACryptoServiceProvider).ExportParameters(True)

    Dim modulus As Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger = New Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(Parameters.Modulus)
    Dim exponent As Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger = New Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(Parameters.Exponent)

    Dim key As RsaKeyParameters = New RsaKeyParameters(True, modulus, exponent) 'exception is thrown here


    Dim sig As ISigner = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA1WITHRSA")
    sig.Init(True, key)


    sig.BlockUpdate(inputData, 0, inputData.Length)
    Dim signature As Byte() = sig.GenerateSignature

    Dim signedString = Convert.ToBase64String(signature)

    Debug.Print("BouncyCastle" & vbCrLf & signedString)
    Encrypt_XML = signedString

End Function
```

Exception: Not a valid RSA modulus Parameter name: modulus

What am I doing wrong here?

**Please note**: I am not very experienced with encryption and find it very challenging to even understand the documentation.

Comment: Regarding the negative sign: Use the constructor `Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(sign As Integer, bytes As Byte())` with `sign = 1`.